# parsing a URL link into segments

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

```
http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?id=fksmf84-8493-45u3
```

How to get this url part `fksmf84-8493-45u3`?? -- this part is keep changing on run time.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
NSString *url = @"http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?id=";
NSArray *parts = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *personID = [parts lastObject];
NSLog(@"My ID: %@", personID);
```

Comment: have you read my response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see:

```
NSString *url = @"http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?id=fksmf84-8493-45u3"; // you forgot to add the id in your test case
NSArray *parts = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *personID = [parts lastObject];
NSLog(@"My ID: %@", personID);
```

**The output:** My ID: fksmf84-8493-45u3

**EDIT:**

To Store the data:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:personID forKey:@"personID"];
```

To read the data:

```
 NSString *personID = [defaults objectForKey:@"personID"];
```

With this method you can easily get the value of the last run. Hope this will help you :) .

Comment: but fksmf84-8493-45u3 that part is keep changing. is it okay to use for an initial anyway? @Masterfego

Comment: So what do you want? just take the id or another thing?

Comment: Just wanna take this part `fksmf84-8493-45u3` but this letters and numbers are keep changing so its not stable. it can be `jdfsfmsf-0000-78h6` for the next time. @Masterfego Is this one still work? I wanna make it dynamic.

Comment: @Dicle It will be fine only until it does not contain the characters on which you split the string i.e '='. Like if the id is "fksmf84-8493=45u3", this would give you '45u3'. You must make sure this id does not contain '='.

Comment: I think you does not explain really what you want. Exlain it very well please. The subject is different that what you want. You want to save this id for anoteher use?

Comment: Whatever i type to url at first.. i am keep getting the same after `=`. Its not changing related to every person ID. @Masterfego @BangOperator

Comment: My first run `http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?id=fksmf84-8493-45u3` im getting this url.. My second run `http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?id=dfsfmsf-0000-78h6` i am getting this. So in my every run url part after `=` is changing how can get this changes for every run ? @Masterfego

Comment: Okay I understand, so if you want to say the value for each run to can use several ways: NSUserDefaults or CoreData.

Comment: any simple example you can give me?. i am trying but having issue.. @Masterfego

Comment: see changes in my response

Comment: Thank you so much @Masterfego

Answer (score 5):

With URL Components:

ObjC:

```
NSString *urlString = "http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?id=fksmf84-8493-45u3";
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:urlString];
NSArray *queryItems = components.queryItems;

for (NSURLQueryItem *queryItem in queryItems) {
    if ([queryItem.name isEqualToString:@"id"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", queryItem.value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Swift:

```
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?id=fksmf84-8493-45u3")
let queryItems = urlComponents?.queryItems
if let id = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "id"}).first?.value {
    print(id)
}
```

Swift 3 (Basically the same - NS):

```
let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://180.160.1.140/webapp/camera?
id=fksmf84-8493-45u3")
let queryItems = urlComponents?.queryItems
if let id = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "id"}).first?.value {
    print(id)
}
```

Comment: Upvote! . This is much better approach then  my answer. Using NSURLQueryItem class :)

Comment: Better way to do +1

Answer (score 3):

To parse all the key value pairs and get them as Dictionary you can use `-parseQueryString:` method.

You can parse your the query string like this...

```
   {
    //...
    NSString * urlQuery              = [url query];
    NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:urlQuery];
    NSString * valueForID = dict["id"];
    //...
    }
    // Waring : Its just a prototype, at production this might need safety checks.
    - (NSDictionary *)parseQueryString:(NSString *)query
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

        for (NSString *pair in pairs)
        {
            NSArray *elements = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString *key = [[elements objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *val = [[elements objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [dict addObject:val forKey:key];
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

**Update** : If targeting iOS versions newer than 7, check Richmond Watkins answer. New api's have been added for the same purpose, Check [NSURLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLQueryItem_Class/)